# Possible to generate a TGT cookie (SSO session) when authenticating via CAS REST Protocol?

Tags: cas

We have an existing CAS 6.0.3 server that is in use for SSO across several applications using the CAS protocol.

I read through the docs, and it looks like CAS creates a TGT cookie (encrypted and signed) after authenticating, and that allows user to access the other applications (CAS clients) without having to sign in again.

Recently, we added an option to use the CAS REST protocol to authenticate a user (generate TGT and then service ticket) to one of the applications, bypassing the CAS login page.  However, that user cannot access the other applications.

Is there a way to generate a SSO session (TGT cookie) when authenticating via CAS REST protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read through the docs, and it looks like CAS creates a TGT cookie (encrypted and signed) after authenticating, and that allows user to access the other applications (CAS clients) without having to sign in again.

Yes.

> Is there a way to generate a SSO session (TGT cookie) when authenticating via CAS REST protocol?

No. REST is stateless. If you use REST, that means you want to have your own SSO management facility that mainly uses CAS as an authentication engine and not an SSO solution. So, you're responsible to manage your own SSO session.

Other folks have resorted into various changes and *hacks* all of which have broken one thing or another over the years. There are ways around this, such that you'd borrow the code from CAS that creates that cookie, attempt to create the cookie yourself, and configure/tweak its properties and paths such that it can be understood by CAS itself. All of this over time would lead to maintenance headaches, premature aging and loss of DNA.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.